# override a method in function object or access instance methods which is passed to a directive in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

need help with JavaScript inheritance for the function object which is passed to directive.
here is my directive function Object and this function is  passed to angular.directive

```
function DDDirective (){
           return {
               restrict: 'EA',
               replace: 'true',
               templateUrl: 'template/abstractLazyLoad.html',
               scope:{
                   id:'@idAttr'
               },
               controller:function($scope){
                   $scope.lazyLoad=funclazyLoadprops();
               }
           }
}
function funclazyLoadprops(){
    return {
        showText: "Show Divisional Directors",
        hideText: "Hide Divisional Directors",
        templateName: 'template/dd/main.html'
    }
}

app.directive('ddDirectiveLazy', DDDirective);

app.directive('ddDirectiveEager',DDDirective);
```

for the directive

> ddDirectiveEager

I want to add some more properties to $scope.lazyLoad , please advice me how.
I tried to use JavaScript prototype inheritance but in controller function I could not access DDDirective  instance methods.

Answer (score 0):

This is hardly the prescribed 'angular way' of doing this, but this should do what you ask:

```
function DDDirective (getProps){
    return function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            replace: 'true',
            templateUrl: 'template/abstractLazyLoad.html',
            scope:{
                id:'@idAttr'
            },
            controller:function($scope){
                $scope.lazyLoad = getProps();
            }
        };
    };
}

function funclazyLoadprops(){
    return {
        showText: "Show Divisional Directors",
        hideText: "Hide Divisional Directors",
        templateName: 'template/dd/main.html'
    }
}

function funcEagerLoadprops(){
    var lazyprops = funclazyLoadprops();
    //attach additional properties here
    return lazyprops;
}

app.directive('ddDirectiveLazy', DDDirective(funclazyLoadprops));

app.directive('ddDirectiveEager',DDDirective(funcEagerLoadprops));
```

Comment: You should rather give access to the `$scope`, otherwise there will be no way to load properties asynchronously from `getProps`.

Comment: You should post a more correct answer.. I didn't have the energy to

Comment: Well, your answer is easy to change to accommodate that. Change `getProps` to `scopeAvailable($scope)`.